# Lubuntu script to reverse order of a list state-capital capital-state

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, cat

I am new to Linux and have a project due in an hour and I know I can use `tac` to reverse a list, but how do you reverse order like:

```
Birmingham-Alabama
Atlanta-Georgia
Topeka-Kansas
```

To this:

```
Alabama-Birmingham
Georgia-Atlanta
Kansas-Topeka
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to think about breaking each line of input into *fields* and then outputing those fields in the desired order: there are **many** tools to do that (pure bash shell, awk, perl, sed ...) - pick one.

Comment: AWK , IMHO, is the most appropriate for such tasks, but pure bash can do ,too.

Comment: I never did get back on here and thank you because I was trying to get that done in time. I got a B in the class so I did ok. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have always only 2 fields:

```
awk  -F- '{print $2"-"$1}' file
```

- This prints just the 2nd field, followed by a dash, followed by the 1st field.

Or with bash:

```
while IFS="-" read -r a b; do echo "$b-$a"; done <file
```

- `IFS` sets the value of bashs internal field separator.
- `read` reads the input line by line and saves the first field to the vairable `$a` and the second field to `$b`.
- `echo` then prints both with a dash.
- `<file` gives the contents of `file` as input.

---

If the number of fields is not always the same:

```
awk  -F- 'OFS="-"{c=1;for(i=NF;i>=1;i--){a[c]=$i;c++}for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=a[i]}}1' file
```

Comment: I never did get back on here and thank you because I was trying to get that done in time. I got a B in the class so I did ok. Thanks for your help.